# Best way to use ActiveRecord models in multiple applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 2 applications that are going to be built (possibly a 3rd API), all are going to use the same database. What is the best way to use the same models across all applications.

Also, what are some of the caveats you have experienced or foresee with this method. Looking for the best solution to this.

Comment: My question is why do they have to be separate apps? Within an app, you can have separate controllers and views, even if the models are shared.

Comment: We are planning on developing a front end application, and the administration application. The point of having them in separate applications (or not, we're discussing) is for source management and to no muck up shared code.

Answer (score 0):

Rails, as opinionated software, prefers a single app, rather than shared models. I've tried it both ways. Are you going to just have copies of the models that can get out of sync? Are you still planning to use Rails' migrations? When you have multiple apps, migrations become difficult. Do you use just one app for migrations? Then you lose the ability to check in migrations along with the code it refers to. Automating builds can become very difficult. You can possibly find a way share migrations too, but that requires some source code management sleight-of-hand which ultimately makes it more difficult to do separate apps and still get everything Rails has to offer. At that point you may want to look into Sinatra.

On the other hand, there's a lot of organizing you can do in a single app that keeps the model domain shared, yet separates the controllers, such as using namespaces or engines. I'd recommend those techniques.